# How to parse symbol ":" in Json String

Tags: java, json, parsing

I want to parse json string into JSONObject but the symbol ":" seems to parse the error

For example -> `"time": "2019-05-28T16:30:29Z"` will be wrong

But changed to `"time": "20190526"` is OK

This is the entire json object:

```
{
    "channel": 922875000,
    "sf": 12,
    "time": "2019-05-28T16:30:29Z",
    "gwip": "192.168.0.180",
    "gwid": "00001c497b431ff5",
    "repeater": "00000000ffffffff",
    "systype": 170,
    "rssi": -103,
    "snr": 20.5,
    "snr_max": 33,
    "snr_min": 18,
    "macAddr": "00000000aabb60ba",
    "data": "00000000",
    "frameCnt": 8,
    "fport": 3
}
```

and the parse code:

```
    try {
        JSONObject sensorObject = new JSONObject(message.toString());
        SensorModel sensorModel = new Gson().fromJson(sensorObject.toString(), SensorModel.class);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

How can I let him keep the same `"2019:05:26"` content?

SensorModel:

```
@Entity
public class SensorModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@NotNull
private long channel;

@NotNull
private int sf;

@NotNull
private String time;

@NotNull
private String gwip;

@NotNull
private String gwid;


private String repeater;


private int systype;


private double rssi;


private double snr;


private double snr_max;


private double snr_min;


private String macAddr;


private String data;


private int frameCnt;


private int fport;

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setChannel(long channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
}

public void setSf(int sf) {
    this.sf = sf;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public void setGwip(String gwip) {
    this.gwip = gwip;
}

public void setGwid(String gwid) {
    this.gwid = gwid;
}

public void setRepeater(String repeater) {
    this.repeater = repeater;
}

public void setSystype(int systype) {
    this.systype = systype;
}

public void setRssi(double rssi) {
    this.rssi = rssi;
}

public void setSnr(double snr) {
    this.snr = snr;
}

public void setSnr_max(double snr_max) {
    this.snr_max = snr_max;
}

public void setSnr_min(double snr_min) {
    this.snr_min = snr_min;
}

public void setMacAddr(String macAddr) {
    this.macAddr = macAddr;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void setFrameCnt(int frameCnt) {
    this.frameCnt = frameCnt;
}

public void setFport(int fport) {
    this.fport = fport;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public long getChannel() {
    return channel;
}

public int getSf() {
    return sf;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public String getGwip() {
    return gwip;
}

public String getGwid() {
    return gwid;
}

public String getRepeater() {
    return repeater;
}

public int getSystype() {
    return systype;
}

public double getRssi() {
    return rssi;
}

public double getSnr() {
    return snr;
}

public double getSnr_max() {
    return snr_max;
}

public double getSnr_min() {
    return snr_min;
}

public String getMacAddr() {
    return macAddr;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public int getFrameCnt() {
    return frameCnt;
}

public int getFport() {
    return fport;
}
}
```

Comment: what string are you trying to parse? `"2019:05:26"`?

Comment: a sensor data from MQTT broker

Comment: Please, post the exact string (minimal necessary piece of code) that you want to parse in order to help you better. `"time": "2019:05:26"` doesn't seem a valid json.

Comment: What library are you parsing with?

Comment: I edited it in my post

Comment: Please, show your `SensorModel` class

Comment: Please explain the difference between your actual input `"time": "2019-05-28T16:30:29Z"` and what you *claim* is your input `"time": "2019:05:26"`

Comment: I updated post.

Comment: JSONObject and GSON are two different JSON libraries. Why are you using both? It really should be one or the other?...

Comment: I don’t seem to have a problem in parsing your input string into a JSONObject (org.json). Perhaps try to articulate your problem in a different way for us to better understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **ObjectMapper** as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.Date;

public class JSONObject {
    private int channel;
    private int sf;
    private Date time;
    private String gwip;
    private String gwid;
    private String repeater;
    private int systype;
    private int rssi;
    private double snr;
    private double snr_min;
    private double snr_max;
    private String macAddr;
    private String data;
    private int frameCnt;
    private int fport;

    public int getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(int channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public int getSf() {
        return sf;
    }

    public void setSf(int sf) {
        this.sf = sf;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getGwip() {
        return gwip;
    }

    public void setGwip(String gwip) {
        this.gwip = gwip;
    }

    public String getGwid() {
        return gwid;
    }

    public void setGwid(String gwid) {
        this.gwid = gwid;
    }

    public String getRepeater() {
        return repeater;
    }

    public void setRepeater(String repeater) {
        this.repeater = repeater;
    }

    public int getSystype() {
        return systype;
    }

    public void setSystype(int systype) {
        this.systype = systype;
    }

    public int getRssi() {
        return rssi;
    }

    public void setRssi(int rssi) {
        this.rssi = rssi;
    }

    public double getSnr() {
        return snr;
    }

    public void setSnr(double snr) {
        this.snr = snr;
    }

    public double getSnr_min() {
        return snr_min;
    }

    public void setSnr_min(double snr_min) {
        this.snr_min = snr_min;
    }

    public double getSnr_max() {
        return snr_max;
    }

    public void setSnr_max(double snr_max) {
        this.snr_max = snr_max;
    }

    public String getMacAddr() {
        return macAddr;
    }

    public void setMacAddr(String macAddr) {
        this.macAddr = macAddr;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getFrameCnt() {
        return frameCnt;
    }

    public void setFrameCnt(int frameCnt) {
        this.frameCnt = frameCnt;
    }

    public int getFport() {
        return fport;
    }

    public void setFport(int fport) {
        this.fport = fport;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JSONObject{" + "channel=" + channel + ", sf=" + sf + ", time=" + time + ", gwip=" + gwip + ", gwid=" + gwid + ", repeater=" + repeater + ", systype=" + systype + ", rssi=" + rssi + ", snr=" + snr + ", snr_min=" + snr_min + ", snr_max=" + snr_max + ", macAddr=" + macAddr + ", data=" + data + ", frameCnt=" + frameCnt + ", fport=" + fport + '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"channel\":922875000,\"sf\":12,\"time\":\"2019-05-28T16:30:29Z\",\"gwip\":\"192.168.0.180\",\"gwid\":\"00001c497b431ff5\",\"repeater\":\"00000000ffffffff\",\"systype\":170,\"rssi\":-103,\"snr\":20.5,\"snr_max\":33,\"snr_min\":18,\"macAddr\":\"00000000aabb60ba\",\"data\":\"00000000\",\"frameCnt\":8,\"fport\":3}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JSONObject obj = objectMapper.readValue(json, JSONObject.class);
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
}
```